# Filesystem Blop or Base64

Tags: android, node.js, image, performance, postgresql

I have read a lot of this 3 ways to send image across the server, but i still don't get what is the best fit to my project.

Basicly im buildling a native app that has the main goal to shoot some fotos, this fotos should be stored in a database, and retrived in a thing like a feed (something like facebook does with news).

I searched a lot and didn't get any info about the choose on mobile apps, because i know that for example using Base64 will give me performance problems (because i count to have thousands of images in the datbaase), and in a mobile app that is a heavy problem.

But what about the other 2 approaches? i am will use Android app as the client, and postgreSQL as datbase, nodeJS will work on the server.

I ask this because i am really worried about the performance on my android aplication.

Thanks!

Comment: You store your images in the PostgreSQL server as type `bytea`. And it doesn't matter if your client consumes those as Base64, as it'll be always one image per request.

Comment: so if in my feed i retrive 20 images i do 20 request will that not cost my app performance?

Comment: Of course it will, especially if you try pulling each image in its full size. That's why any real system would automatically create thumbnails, so they can be consumed first by the client. There are server-side modules for Node.js that can create a thumbnail from an image which you can add into the system at the same time as the real image ;) There are ways to optimize these things, but it would be too broad a question to fit into one answer here.

Comment: hmm nice answer thank you,i wonder isn't there other way at the initial fase to put that a little more optimized instead of just save as bytea?? like using bulp or filesystem or base64 is that a good choice? for example as base64 i need just 1 request right?

Comment: `bytea` is the optimum format, as it is the binary.

Comment: Why would you store the files in the database? It's usually NOT the recommend practice. Even if you do, and the images do not change, I'd recommend putting a cache server in front of it.

Comment: Why store the images in the DB? That's normally the preferred way to do things as it's not nearly as efficient if you don't need all the ACID stuff the DB has -- and usually you don't with images.

Comment: so i should go for the bytea and try to speed up the requests with nodejs?